# how can I play flash content in Chrome browser with new grounds flash player on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, flash

I have downloaded and installed the new grounds flash player. I can play a flash game with it. Now I would like to play the flash game in Chrome browser using new grounds flash player. As far as I know I  have to change some path  in some files stored on my PC, so that Chrome browser knows that it should open the swf with the new grounds flash player. My operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: btw the swf file is already properly embedded within the website. So this is not the problem. The problem is that Chrome doesn't pick the already installed new grounds flash player to open the swf.

Answer (score 0):

Go to chrome://settings/content/flash, unblock Flash in Chrome, toggle the Block sites from running a Flash button to Ask first.

Then you can change the registry setting mentioned in this [article](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7084871?hl=en#zippy=%2Coption-allow-chrome-to-manage-its-version-of-flash-player-recommended).